# Heroku rails console automatically exits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, console-application

I'm running a simple rails active query command on 300,000 records.

Why does the heroku console automatically exit?

```
def is_number? string
  true if Float(string) rescue false
end
documents = []
DocumentText.all.each do |t|
  if is_number?(t.src)
    documents << t
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easier to filter on the database side e.g.

```
DocumentText
  .pluck('src::float as src')
  .where("src ~ '^([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*|[.][0-9]+)$'");nil
```

Here we cast src to a float where src meets the given pattern. The casting may or may not be important to you but the where clause will filter your results in the database rather than loading them all then filtering them.

Comment: `DocumentText.where(...).pluck('src::float as src')`

Comment: What was I even thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

try to avoid loading lot of data on repl by

```
DocumentText.select('src').each do |t|
    if is_number?(t.src)
        documents << t
    end
end;nil
```

Answer (score 0):

best would be to do this in batches, so you won't load all records at once into memory

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each

```
DocumentText.find_each do |t|
  next unless !!Float(t.src) rescue false
  documents << t
end; nil
```

`nil` at the end won't print result into the console, you can also use a number `0`

Answer (score 0):

There is no error message but the problem is because the server ran out of memory.